# "Too many attribute references" warning

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framework

I have an app, where some fragments only consist of ListViews. Some of my users with low-end devices experience a phenomenon, where a fragment simply can not display the data. When they enter the fragment I display a ProgressBar, and this ProgressBar seems to spin forever.

So I bought a low-end device and am facing the same problem. I get the data for the ListView with a network request to my backend API, but the answer is never returned. The only warning I see so far is

```
W/ResourceType﹕ Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x01010034
```

I could not find much about this error in the web but it seems like this warning is logged here https://github.com/SciAps/android-frameworks-base/blob/c693209edc3696884c1fcd59790dda0b9811d017/libs/utils/ResourceTypes.cpp#L1573, but I don't understand what the Android code is doing there.

Anyone has a clue about what's going on here, what's the problem and how I can fix that?

**BTW** I use RoboSpice and Retrofit to do the network requests. The background service that is responsible for getting the data is stopped after this warning, that's why I never get back data.

**EDIT** As far as I can tell not seeing the data has nothing to do with the warning. Anyway, what does this warning mean and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Do you have an xml file (for themes or styles maybe) where a node has more than 20 attributes ? I'm really not sur about it but if this method (Theme::getAttribute) is reading attributes from an xml theme, it seems like its limited to 20. it's worth checking it and maybe trying to remove attributes if its the case...

Comment: I geot the same error when i added a "theme" to a textview in xml.
But the style only has 2 attributes not 20.

Answer (score 17):

I accidentally applied a style as a theme on a view, which resulted in this warning showing up. In the view's XML, by using `style="@style/MyStyle"` instead of `android:theme="@style/MyStyle"` I was able to stop the warnings.

Comment: I had this in my XML too, changed as you suggested but nothing changed and still have the "Too many attribute references" warning. So, it's not this

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the most upvoted answer by @Corclark was not entirely accurate in my case. I got the same warning, but didn't have the `style="@style/MyStyle"` set anywhere. I experimented a bit and found out it was actually this line that caused the warning for me:

```
android:theme="@style/My.Switch"
```

Then, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283105/too-many-attribute-references-warning-possible-causes). Changing the style of `My.Switch` to

```
<style name="My.Switch" parent="">
    <item name="android:background">@color/dark_grey</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/Unpluq</item>
</style>
```

resolved the warning for me. Hope it might still be helpful to some.

Comment: This worked for me too, but why did it work? Why is setting `parent` to empty a solution?

Comment: Not entirely sure, it seems to have something to do with the way styles are linked, @Ben's answer to the question: "I had the same issue and at some point an attribute chain was created. By removing the parent the chain is broken so you should be good."

Answer (score 2):

It happens when using ContextThemeWrapper for creating new ElementViews

```
TextView txtView= new TextView(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.styleName));
```

Comment: So you reproduced the error? Can you explain what happens, why, and if necessary, how to avoid it?

Comment: Use `TextView txtView= new TextView(context, null, 0, R.style.styleName);` instead.