# Spinner Crash on click

Tags: java, android, spinner

I am Using `Android-Studio`

I was creating an app it was working fine, after few days of coding

my spinner went completely broken !
*.... I don't think it's because of other codes?*

When I Click on it app crashes...

Here is my Spinner codes :

```
          Spinner s1;
          String[] s1c = {"All","Filter1", "Filter2", "Filter3", "Filter4", "Filter5", "Filter6"};


           s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cater);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, s1c);
            s1.setAdapter(adapter);
            s1.setSelection(0);s1.setEnabled(true);


    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//                filter1=s1c[position];
//                if(mayload ==1) {
//                    loadlist();
//                }else{
//                    mayload=1;
//                }

/*Even Commented anything....*/
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Spinner XML : *..... does it matter ?...*

```
   <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/cater"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" />
```

LogCat :

```
09-02 16:12:22.603 28394-28394/com.example.discopc.yubismart W/ResourceType: Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x01010099
    09-02 16:12:22.603 28394-28394/com.example.discopc.yubismart W/ResourceType: Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x0101009a
    09-02 16:12:22.603 28394-28394/com.example.discopc.yubismart W/ResourceType: Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x0101009b
    09-02 16:12:22.625 28394-28394/com.example.discopc.yubismart I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 28394 SIG: 9
```

It dosent even say `*Example* Stoped working` it will exit instantly...

[Full Xml](https://pastebin.com/NaiFmLpW)

[Full Code](https://pastebin.com/k4MJNH7T)

**Things I tried**

Clean Project ...

Comment: did you use any style in style.xml for spinner or other view in that layout

Comment: Full Logcat : https://pastebin.com/k4MJNH7T

Comment: android:theme="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material"

try removing this

Comment: wait , that worked ! i had that some where in Styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check **style** and **clean** project and **build** it

Comment: em,it was the problem i think i told once? :D

Comment: Click File-Invalid Cashes/Restart Before that backup your whole app

Comment: Also refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283105/too-many-attribute-references-warning-possible-causes

Answer (score 0):

This code is working on my device.If you are using **Android Studio**:
Goto **"Build"** menu and select **"Clean Project"** and then try running it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a `android:theme="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material"` 
Some where in Styles

I Removed that and it worked fine...

Thanks to  **vikas kumar**